# Azure build pipeline sporadic error, [CredentialProvider]Device flow authentication failed

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline

This happened maybe once every 2 weeks, but lately it happens a few times until the build succeeds once.

GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.uitest/3.0.9/xamarin.uitest.3.0.9.nupkg
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(128,5): Error :     [CredentialProvider]Device flow authentication failed. User was presented with device flow, but didn't react within 90 seconds.

----- Update ----
After further digging in the logs, I found out that it was due to an 401 (Unauthorized) access to a private feed (in the same organization as the project where the pipeline fails).
A temporary solution was to remove the specific *.csproj, that needed this private feed, from the solution build config, and also remove the private feed from the pipeline. This got the pipeline working again.

---- More Pipeline infos ----
I can't post the entire code here.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  configuration: NugetB

steps:
- task: MSBuild
  displayName: 'MSBuild'
  inputs:
    solution: '**\xxSolutionxx.sln'
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    msbuildArguments: '/t:restore;build;pack /p:PackageOutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /p:RestoreAdditionalProjectSources=https://urlToPrivateFeedInTheSameOrganization /p:configuration=$(configuration) /p:NuGetInteractive="true"'
```

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I've added an update

Comment: If you are access the private feed, please try to add the NuGet authenticate task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure build pipeline sporadic error, [CredentialProvider]Device flow authentication failed

If you have task/script access to azure ariftact feed in your pipeline, then please try to use the `System.AccessToken` variable to authenticate a pipeline to a private Azure Artifacts feed or try to reset your PAT.

You could check [this document](https://andrewmatveychuk.com/how-to-access-private-powershell-repository-from-azure-pipeline/) for some more details.

Besides, if above not resolve your question, please share how did you access the artifact and the build pipeline configuration.